# Is it possible to tweet on twitter using java api without outh

Tags: java, oauth, twitter

Is it possible to tweet on twitter using java api without outh ? i.e username/ password passed in parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not anymore, as they now fully depend on the OAuth-protocol. More information lies ahead: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth